# AWS Python Virtualenv where do I put boto.cfg

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, authentication, virtualenv, boto

I made a virtualenv for python. I have some python files that I've used successfully but now that I'm trying to use virtualenv to package the files for lambda I can't for the life of me figure out where to put the boto.cfg file for aws authorization. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-overview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using boto3 in Lambda, the common practice is to "grant" a role to the Lambda function that give it the permissions it needs. This is "role based permissions" versus "user based permissions".

[This document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-overview.html#access-control-manage-access-intro) explains it conceptually, but like most AWS documentation will leave you wondering "Now that you **sold** me on what to do, **HOW** do I do it?" (That is to say I find most AWS documentation is targeted to CTOs and IT Directors who approve budgets and partner selection, rather than developers/operators who actually have to do the work.)

I hope this helps!

[image: Screenshot showing Permissions and Trust Relationships of a Role assigned to a Lambda function]

Comment: that was great information. I agree AWS articles leave a lot to desire.